# imread function in Octave doesn't work, and throw out an exception

Tags: image, octave

I want to use imread function to load a .tif image in Octave-4.2.1, but there is an exception as follows:

> Magick++ exception:
>     Magick:E:\CV\Digital image processing\img\a.tif:Null
>   count for "Tag 34026" (type 1, writecount -3, passcount 1). (_TIFFVSetField) reported by coders/tiff.c:793 (TIFFErrors) .
>   error: called from  **imread** at line 80 column 10
>       imageIO at line 117 column 26
>       imread at line 106 column 30

but not all .tif images cannot be loaded, that's really weird

Comment: Looks like an invalid TIFF file. Can you open the file using other programs?

Comment: It can be opened with windows-photo-viewer.  I also tried with matlab, there's a warnning :"Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 67%".   The image size : "600*600(pixel), 267dpi Horizontal, 267dpi vertical, 8bit"

Comment: to debug this you have to upload an image which throws the error